# Relative Positioning (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone

Given two labels (or views), how would you automatically move (reposition) the lower one relative to the changing vertical size of the upper one.

Answer (score 0):

You resize or move them by changing their frame property.

Comment: yes, but how would you do it "automatically", so if the upper one resizes so the lower one moves in relation...

Comment: What do you mean automatically?  Do you expect the iPhone OS to move them for you?  You can get the OS to resize subviews inside a view when the view size changes but that's not the same as moving one label when an adjacent label changes size.

Comment: Yes I expected to find some sort of layout managment that could do this. Hence the question...

Comment: There is only automatic resizing, no automatic moving them in relation to each other when they change in size.  When you resize a subview you have to resize/move the subviews around it in your code.